# Restoring Elasticsearch indices in s3

Tags: elasticsearch-curator

I am using helm chart to install Elasticsearch curator, https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch-curator, there is option in the values to add the s3 bucket https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/elasticsearch-curator, I am not quite sure if the curator sends indices which it deletes during cronjob to s3 or it sends all the indices to s3?

I tried adding the s3 information but did-not find indices in s3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how the helm chart is doing things, but Curator makes API calls to Elasticsearch—nothing more, nothing less. Elasticsearch must have a repository defined if you are taking snapshots. If you are creating a new cluster and want to restore indices from an existing S3 repository, you must re-create the repository in the new cluster with the same path & bucket arguments. Only then will Curator be able to restore indices from a snapshot already existing in S3.